# Change Color Visio shape programatically in c#

Tags: c#, colors, cell, visio, bpmn

i want to change the color of a BPMN-Shape in Visio by Code. What i've done so far is changing the value from the "LineColor" Cell of the ShapeSheet in Visio with the following code-snippet:

```
 _startShape.CellsU["LineColor"].FormulaForceU = "=RGB(255,0,0)";
```

However, Shapes that I drawed myself are not changing in color. The Information/Value in the ShapeSheet-Cell is changing but the color is still not visible. I read about the GUARD-function which is protecting the cells, but the `FormulaForceU` should ignore the GUARD.

Imported Shapes are changing as expected! Just the self-drawed are not changing to red (RGB(255,0,0).

I can't figure out why! Has anyone experienced the same?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the shape is a group, then you need to change the sub-shapes as well.

Comment: How to check if a shape is a group? it is a normal "task" shape of bpmn

Comment: shp being the current shape. shp.shapes is the collection of subshapes... for each subshp in shp.shapes ... and so on. Note even the subshapes can be groups.

Comment: I am only addressing shp and not shp.shapes.... so i don't have a collection of sub-shapes.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. When iterating through the shapes collection of the page, you need to do it recursively. If the shp.shapes.count > 0 then iterate over the sub-shapes.

Comment: alright, got it working now. Right now i'm just looping over all subshapes of every shape i want to change... not very nice, but it works... is it really necessary to change all of the subshapes or is there one specific subshape which is enough to change? Thanks

Comment: Each subshape can have its own colour. Either you hard code its colour (RGB...), or you reference the colour of its parent (eg sheet.123!linecolor). In the second case the deep iteration is needed only once - since the subshapes will reference the the color from the higher level. Think also about format protection, which may prevent the reformatting of the subshapes.

Comment: @dnks23 Do you have any code to share on this? I understand what y4cine is referring to however I cannot make it work. I recorded a macro and looked into it and it backs up what y4cine was saying.

Answer (score 1):

select any shape, click by right mouse button. Find **Group** drop-list, if there **Ungroup** option not greyed then selected shape is group

[image: select any shape, click by right mouse button. Find **Group** drop-list, if there **Ungroup** option then selected shape is group]

Comment: Found the option. Strange thing is, that the shapes that are changing the color(like i mentioned above) are a group too. So this can't be the trick....

Answer (score 1):

Also you can see "shape's anatomy" via **Drawing Explorer Window**, you can activate this window on **Developer** tab on ribbon

[image: Drawing explorer window]

Answer (score 0):

Try use visio default systems color constant - vbRed or 2 - [VisDefaultColors Enumeration (Visio)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Visio-VBA/articles/visdefaultcolors-enumeration-visio?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> _startShape.CellsU["LineColor"].FormulaForceU = 2;

Comment: you have to enter a string value, not an integer

Answer (score 0):

i find this advice (use CellsSRC syntax) in russian stackoverflow post 
[Change text color in Visio](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/509591/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-visio)

> Visio.Cell colorCell = shape.get_CellsSRC((short)Visio.VisSectionIndices.visSectionCharacter,(short)Visio.VisRowIndices.visRowCharacter,(short)Visio.VisCellIndices.visCharacterColor);
>   colorCell.FormulaForceU = "RGB(0, 255, 255)";

Comment: but this is changing the same property/cell i am addressing in my solution right now?! Seems the only difference is that your solution saves a cell-object first?

Comment: This shape contain some sub-shapes. And their don't inherite parent shape properties. You need find sub-shape which geometry same as parent shape geometry, and change it color property

Answer (score 0):

I have solution that is working for me. I do not believe it is the best because as Surrogate pointed out you can dive into the shapes anatomy and look at exactly what you need to change. However I still cannot figure out how to precisely get the shape that needs to change without this iterative approach. This code is changing the shapes line color without side effects.

```
public static void HighlightShape(Shape shape)
{
    if (shape == null) {
        return;
    }

    var processList = new Queue<Shape>();
    processList.Enqueue(shape);

    var allShapes = new List<Shape>();
    allShapes.Add(shape);

    while (processList.Count > 0) 
    {
        var s = processList.Dequeue();
        allShapes.Add(s);
        if (s.Shapes != null) {
            foreach (Shape subshape in s.Shapes) {
                processList.Enqueue(subshape);
            }
        }
    }

    foreach (Shape s in allShapes) 
    {
        s.CellsU["LineColor"].FormulaForceU = "THEMEGUARD(RGB(255,255,0))";
    }
}
```